# Minimizing the misclassification rate

Tags: machine-learning, decision-theory

I am reading the book [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/), and have a specific question from a text snippet. I'll state a few lines in the text

*Suppose that our goal is simply to make as few misclassifications as possible.
We need a rule that assigns each value of x to one of the available classes. Such a rule will divide the input space into regions **R<sub>k</sub>** called
decision regions , one for each class, such that all points in **R<sub>k</sub>**
are assigned to class **C<sub>k</sub>**. {..skipping few lines}.In order to find the optimal decision rule, consider first of all the case of two classes, as in the cancer problem for instance. A mistake occurs when an input vector belonging to class **C<sub>1</sub>** is assigned to class **C<sub>2</sub>**
or vice versa. The probability of this occurring is given by*

$$\begin{equation}
p(mistake)=p(x \in R_1 ,C_2)+p(x \in R_2,C_1)
\end{equation}
$$
$$\begin{equation}
\hspace{5em}=\int_{R_1} p(x,C_2)dx+ \int_{R_2} p(x,C_1)dx
\end{equation}
$$

*To minimize p(mistake) we should arrange that each **x** is assigned to whichever class has the smaller value of the integrand in the above equation.Thus if **p(x,C<sub>1</sub>) >p(x,C<sub>2</sub>)** for a given value of **x** , then we should assign that **x** to class  **C<sub>1</sub>**.*

Can anyone explain what is the last line supposed to mean? From what I could understand, if the probablity of a point **x** in the region **R<sub>2</sub>** is classified to be in the region **C<sub>2</sub>**, this is increasing the misclassification. But the sentence says the opposite.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For this you don't need to think about regions yet. For a given point **x**, you calculate

- the probability that **x** belongs to **C<sub>1</sub>** = p(x,C<sub>1</sub>)
- the probability that **x** belongs to **C<sub>2</sub>** = p(x,C<sub>2</sub>)

You will of course simply  choose the class with the higher probability. That is what he states in the last sentence: if **p(x,C<sub>1</sub>) > p(x,C<sub>2</sub>)**, then choose the class **C<sub>1</sub>**, otherwise choose **C<sub>2</sub>**.

Now lets think about regions: The region where you will choose **C<sub>1</sub>** due to the above stated decision rule is denoted by **R<sub>1</sub>**, similarly the region where **C<sub>2</sub>** is chosen is denoted by **R<sub>2</sub>**. Now the error consists of:

- Points **x** which would belong to **C<sub>2</sub>** but are in the region **R<sub>1</sub>**
- Points **x** which would belong to **C<sub>1</sub>** but are in the region **R<sub>2</sub>**

The probability of error is thus the integral over the probability that a point **x** in the region **R<sub>1</sub>** belongs to **C<sub>2</sub>** plus the integral over the probability that a point **x** in the region **R<sub>2</sub>** belongs to the class **C<sub>1</sub>**.

Does this help to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last line:

> Thus if p(x, C1) >p(x, C2) for a given value of x , then we should
> assign that x to class C1.

The above two p are the joint distribution of finding the two classes C1 and C2 at given input x. After determining the two regions, R1 and R2, we are left to compute the misclassification error, i.e., p(mistake).  The p(mistake) is minimized when we follow the above rule in the quotes. If you analyze Figure 1.24, shown in the book, the optimal decision boundary is at x_0. The regions based at the point x_0 give us the lowest p(mistake). If we don't follow the above-stated rule, we'll arrive at a solution similar to the one at x = x_hat.